# Azurerm powershell Cannot bind parameter and Cannot convert the value

Tags: powershell, azure

even I can see the virtual network still can not get the specific virtual network subnet info from Azure powershell1.4.0.

PS C:\Users\mwang> Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork |more |Select-String name |more

Name              : ToolBelt
ResourceGroupName : ToolBelt
                        "Name": "ToolBelt_GTPROD.local",
                        "Name": "ToolBelt_GTPROD",
Name              : TestVNet
ResourceGroupName : BI-Reporting-VPN
                        "Name": "FrontEnd",
                        "Name": "Backend",
                        "Name": "GatewaySubnet",
Name              : GTGLOBAL.LOCAL
ResourceGroupName : GTGLOBAL
                        "Name": "GTGLOBAL1",
                        "Name": "GatewaySubnet",
                        "Name": "NetworkLoadBalancer",
                        "Name": "BarracudaLB",
                        "Name": "DMZ",
Name              : GTLB
ResourceGroupName : GTLB
                        "Name": "default",
Name              : KW-network
ResourceGroupName : KW
                        "Name": "default",

PS C:\Users\mwang> Get-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -VirtualNetwork KW-network
Get-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig : Cannot bind parameter 'VirtualNetwork'. Cannot convert the "KW-network" value
of type "System.String" to type "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Network.Models.PSVirtualNetwork".
At line:1 char:55
+ Get-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -VirtualNetwork KW-network
+                                                       ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Network.GetAzureVirtualNetworkSu
   bnetConfigCommand

PS C:\Users\mwang> Get-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -VirtualNetwork GTGLOBAL.LOCAL
Get-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig : Cannot bind parameter 'VirtualNetwork'. Cannot convert the "GTGLOBAL.LOCAL"
value of type "System.String" to type "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Network.Models.PSVirtualNetwork".
At line:1 char:55
+ Get-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -VirtualNetwork GTGLOBAL.LOCAL
+                                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Network.GetAzureVirtualNetworkSu
   bnetConfigCommand

PS C:\Users\mwang>

Answer (score 1):

The error clearly states that it cannot bind a string value . It should be passed as a variable.Here is an example below

```
    $vnetname=Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -Name <value> -ResourceGroupName <value>
```

now pass this variable to the getsubnet command as below:

```
    Get-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetconfig -VirtualNetwork $vnetname
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a wrong parameter in the last call:

```
Get-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -VirtualNetwork GTGLOBAL.LOCAL
```

It should be something like:

```
Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork "GTGLOBAL.LOCAL" | Get-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig ...
```